# local server takes time to update clamav db

Tags: clamav

I'm serving cvd files from a local server, when I run freshclam on my server it takes some runes until the daily.cvd is updated even though the remote version was updated a while ago.

The clamav version I'm using is 0.102.4-r1

freshclam.conf I'm using is:

```
   DatabaseDirectory /data
   LogSyslog yes
   UpdateLogFile /logs/freshclam.log
   LogTime yes
   PidFile /run/clamav/freshclam.pid
   DatabaseOwner root
   LogVerbose yes
   DatabaseMirror database.clamav.net
   ScriptedUpdates no.  (for serving as local server)
   SafeBrowsing yes
   Bytecode yes
```

some focused logs from freshclam run which not update the local daily.cvd even though it indicates a newer version remotely:

```
daily database available for update (local version: 26009, remote version: 26010)
*The daily.cvd database downloaded from https://database.clamav.net is one version older than advertised in the DNS TXT record.
Database test passed.
daily.cvd updated (version: 26009, sigs: 4351133, f-level: 63, builder: raynman)
```

Do I need to change my configuration or is it a bug on the 102.4 clamav version?

Comment: stack overflow community if for questions related to programming, you might want to ask a moderator to move your question to super user or server fault commnity, since this would increase your chances to get some help with this problem.